# Getting the Anchor Link by using Jsoup

Tags: java, html, anchor, jsoup, href

I am getting the href by using

`Jsoup.parse(hrefLink, "").select("a[href]").attr("href")`

where `hrefLink` is founded hreflink.

What I want to do is, to get outgoing links from the current web page if they match with my condition. Unfortunately, because of anchorlinks, I cannot always get outgoing links, but instead I want to be able to get other hrefs that anchorlink is redirecting to. For instance:

Given page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baked_potato

where citation [10] anchorlink has two outgoing links. I want to be able to get them. How can I do that by using Jsoup? If that's not possible with Jsoup, what else can I use?

Answer (score 0):

HTML anchors (and links to fragments in general) only indicate a position in a document that a browser will scroll to when the anchor is navigated to (through a link or directly via a URL with a #fragment); they don't "redirect" to anything.  The relationship between the links is not encoded in the document, so Jsoup (or any other library) cannot determine this, in general.  Your program will need some semantic knowledge of the pages it's processing.

In your Wikipedia example, after finding the `li#cite_note-10` element, you can select all child `a` elements, then use `absUrl("href")` to get the link target and filter out any links that refer to the same page.  (Currently just checking that the `href` attribute doesn't start with `#` is enough, but in general a document can link to itself with a full URL too.)  But this depends on the semantics of the document, not just its syntax -- a future Wikipedia redesign may move where the citation link points so that the outgoing links are no longer children of the citation link target, and your code will break.